# HTML/CSS: Putting a div with background color over text, with text still selectable

Tags: html, css

I want to highlight an area on a page, the page consists of text and images.

I don't want to stop the user from selecting the text, but I do want to have a semi-transparent yellow rectangle over the top of the text.

How can I do this without stopping the user from being able to select or interact with anything underneath the highlight div?

Example

```
<h1>test</h2>
<h1>line two</h1>
<h3>Why can't I select "test"? by itself</h3>
<span style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:150px;height:150px;background-color:yellow;opacity:0.1;-webkit-touch-callout: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;"></span>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yoz1sk0x/)

Comment: You could make text semi-transparent or place your yellow rectangle besides the text.

Comment: Set z-index of your spans to -1 or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to the span.

```html
<h1>test</h2><h1>line two</h1><h3>Why can't I select "test"? by itself</h3>
<span style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:150px;height:150px;background-color:yellow;opacity:0.1;-webkit-touch-callout: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;pointer-events: none;"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following style to your span:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

It will allow the mouse to "go through" the span

```html
<h1>test<br />line two</h1>
<h2>Why can't I select "test"? by itself</h2>
<span style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;display:block;width:150px;height:150px;background-color:yellow;opacity:0.5;-webkit-touch-callout: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;pointer-events:none;"></span>
```

Please note, you have an error in your closing h2 tag and also if you want an h1 to go over 2 lines, use a `br` instead of closing and reopening it

[More information about `pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

If you are just wanting an opaque background-colour without making the foreground opaque, you can use and rgba color:

```css
/*for example only*/
body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/800/city/1/);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:rgba(255,255,0,0.5)">
  <h1>test<br/>line two</h1>
  <h3>Why can't I select "test"? by itself</h3>
</div>
```

[More information on rgba colors](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work

You have to add position: relative; z-index: 9999; to your h1 tags

```
<h1 style="position: relative; z-index: 9999;">test</h1><h1 style="position: relative; z-index: 9999;">line two</h1><h3 style="position: relative; z-index: 9999;">Why can't I select "test"? by itself</h3>
<span style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:150px;height:150px;background-color:yellow;opacity:0.1;-webkit-touch-callout: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;"></span>
```

Comment: Can you explain why 9999 and not, for instance, 1?

Comment: Sorry, it's work also with z-index 1 but if you add an other z-index to span will not work with z-index 1 but for now it will work also with 1

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in two ways:

1. Set `pointer-events: none;` to span tag
2. Set `position: relative;opacity:0.5; z-index: 1;` for text tags/elements [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yoz1sk0x/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Although `pointer-events: none;` should do the trick for you, another (quite new) powerful way for creating a overlay effect is the `blend-mode` property.

https://dev.opera.com/articles/getting-to-know-css-blend-modes/

Here's an example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meLgjL

An advantage over your solution is that you don't need extra elements for styling the content.

http://caniuse.com/#search=blend-mode (not yet supported in IE or Edge)